# Device showing as disabled while trying to instrument the app + Xamarin.iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, instrumentation, visual-studio-mac, xcode-instruments

I am trying to instrument an app by connecting the device to Visual Studio Community for Mac (version 7.3.3). I am able to install and run the app in device, but when instrumenting its showing as disabled.[image]

Comment: I would assume that is because your phone has a newer version of iOS than that is supported by the version of Xcode that you have installed.

Comment: But i am able to debug and run the app in my iPhone. Its displaying the device properly during that time.

Comment: @SushiHangover You were correct, it was due to mismatch in iOS and Xcode/VisualStudio versions.

Answer (score 0):

After updating the Xcode, Visual Studio (for Mac) and the iOS version the device is getting detected now. Its showing in enabled state. I have updated my Xcode to 9.4.1 and Visual Studio to 7.5.3 and iOS version to 11.4.

In case you are facing the same issue make sure everything is up todate.